# identify similarities in a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, similarity

I have a dataset of customers:

```
age  height  weight eye_colour
30    174    74       Nan
20    191    71       Nan
28    165    56       Brown
...
```

I would like to identify similarities between customers where the `eye_colour` is `Nan` in order to help identify the cause of this missing value.

Is there any method to help identify similarities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general identifying similarities is done with clustering, but in this case what you're looking for is a potential pattern in the data leading to a missing value in a specific column, right? So I would try to train a decision tree using all the columns except the target one as features, and using a binary class indicating whether the target column has a missing value or not. Visualizing the decision tree obtained after training  should show the pattern if there is one.

Comment: Thank you Erwan, I will try your method and inform you :)